# How to do a Conditional Join in Sql using Linq in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq, join

I am trying to convery a Sql query to a C# LINQ join. I tried but I could not achieve this. This corresponding query in SQL works as-is:

```
SELECT pj01.CLID from us20
INNER JOIN pj01 ON pj01.PJID = 
( 
     CASE 
     WHEN (us20.BKNM = 'PJID')

     THEN us20.BKID

     WHEN (us20.BKNM = 'PSID')

     THEN 
     (
         SELECT PJID FROM pj02 WHERE CLID = us20.CLID AND PSID = us20.BKID
     ) 
     END 
)
```

My Linq attempt, which does not work - Data does not come:

```
var result = 
         from us20 in Us20Repository.GetAll()
         join pj01 in Pj01Repository.GetAll() on new
         {
             PJID =
             (us20.BKNM == "PJID" ?
                    us20.BKID :
                    (
                       us20.BKNM == "PSID" ?
                       (
                         (from pj02 in Pj02Repository.GetAll()
                         where
                              pj02.CLID == us20.CLID &&
                              pj02.PSID == us20.BKID
                         select new
                         {
                               PJID = pj02.PJID
                         }).First().PJID
                      ) :
                      ""
                   )
             )
         } equals new { PJID = pj01.PJID }
         select new
         {
             CLID = pj01.CLID
         };
```

How can I do this? Is this possible?

Comment: Once the query has been generated, can you hover over `result` and show us the SQL it is generating?

Comment: 23,000 line data( data = "100") in SQL queries, Linq : 0

Comment: I meant the result *before* it's been materialized. It should show you the SQL (don't call `ToList()` or any other materialization method on it). Leave it as `IQueryable` and inspect it.

Comment: .AsQueryable().First().PJID unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

This is an example syntax. Hope this will help

```
dbContext.SourceTable         // source
                      .Join(dbContext.TargetTable,         // target
                                        source=> source.Id,          // FK
                                        target=> target.Id,   // PK
                                        (source, target) => new { source= source,target=target}).Where(x=>x.source.somefield!=x.target.somefield) // project result
                                    .Select(x => x.source); //the output
```

Comment: I think the OP knows how to do a regular join. It's just in this case the join is more complicated than specifying a key, it's conditional.

Comment: I just told you Linq

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous types by default do not support a clever `Equals` implementation but simply use `Object.Equals`, which is why it totally makes sense to me that the query returns no result. This would be perfectly reasonable if your LINQ-Provider fails to translate your query to SQL but runs the join locally. Try to omit the anonymous type in the join operator:

```
var result = 
     from us20 in Us20Repository.GetAll()
     join pj01 in Pj01Repository.GetAll() on 
         (us20.BKNM == "PJID" ?
                us20.BKID :
                (
                   us20.BKNM == "PSID" ?
                   (
                     (from pj02 in Pj02Repository.GetAll()
                     where
                          pj02.CLID == us20.CLID &&
                          pj02.PSID == us20.BKID
                     select new
                     {
                           PJID = pj02.PJID
                     }).First().PJID
                  ) :
                  ""
               )
         )
     equals pj01.PJID
     select new
     {
         CLID = pj01.CLID
     };
```